# code::blocks can debug code but not run it

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

I have C99 project using Allegro 5 library.
When I debug code with no breakpoints, it runs succesfully, but when I simply run it, it crashes.

I expect some memory leaks in code(I know valgrind.) but why does my program behave so differently?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Perhaps you haven't rebuilded the Release version of your project and it runs the faulty one?

Comment: I rebuilt whole project and have same issue, either release or debug version doesnt work.

Comment: have you checked your tool chains?

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using? and What type of crashes do you find. Sometimes Crashes are due to problems in inner functions rather than code::blocks itself. Also, compile with `-Wextra` (Extra Warning)   in Code::Blocks  to see all warnings